# Translating from informal logical notation to formal logical notation

Tags: propositional-calculus

While introducing formal logical notation, the book I'm reading says the following:

> "$\forall x$ in $D$. $P(x)$" can be written as "$\forall x (x$ in $D \rightarrow P(x)$".
>
> "$\exists x$ in $D$ such that $P(x)$" can be written as "$\exists x(x$ in $D \wedge P(x))$".

Why is it that the first conversion uses $\rightarrow$ while the second $\wedge$? The way I see, the symbol $\wedge$ can be used in both the statements and they should work.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the first one can hold even if $D$ is empty, but for the second one a special $x$ must exist in D

Compare these two:

(**a**) Every leopard that lives in the north pole has spots on its skin.

(**b**) There exists a leopard that lives in the north pole and has spots on its skin.

It will be good to note what would happen if we use $\land$ in instead of $\to$, compare these two:
$D={\text{Set of leopards living in the north pole}}$

$P(x) \iff x \text{ has spots on its skin}$

(**a**) Every $x$ is a leopard that lives in the north pole and has spots on its skin. ($\forall x,x \in D \land Spot(x)$)

(**b**) Every leopard that lives in the north pole has dots on its skin.
($\forall x,x\in D\to Spot(x))$)

Comment: Very nice. So this means the first statement is a conditional in disguise.

Comment: @dotslash Thanks, I updated my answer.You may like to have a look at it. :)

Comment: Very nice! It is even more clear now. Thanks a ton! :)